Is there a method of exporting table data from Excel into a Word document template, based on criteria in columns?
I have requirements in an Excel file. Now we want to build a requirement selector. In which sales people can just click all the groups of requirements (checkmarks) and add them into a pre-specified Word document. The goal is to have one single source of truth for the requirements, and also to enable sales people to create requirement documents from scratch but also tailored to the specifics of that customers' wishes.
I tried with VBA, code is down below. It creates a Word document. But it only outputs the last row of data, not any of the others I highlighted with 'JA' (='Yes').
This is the data:



Requirement
Heading group
Select group
Include (JA/NEE)




req 1
Group 1
Group 1
JA


req 2
Group 2
Group 2
JA


Zin 1Zin 3Zin 5
Group 3
Group 3
JA



data screenshot
This is the button i added with VBA:
Sub GenerateWordDoc()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentGroup As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim reqText As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Update to your sheet name if necessary
    
    ' Create Word Application and Document
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    
    ' Get the last row of the data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through the "Include (JA/NEE)" column (D) to find groups marked as "JA"
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' If "JA" is selected in the "Include (JA/NEE)" column
        If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "JA" Then
            currentGroup = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Get the group name from the "Select Group" column (C)
            
            ' Add the group name as a heading in the Word document
            WordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "Group: " & currentGroup
            
            ' Initialize the text variable for the requirements
            reqText = ""
            
            ' Loop through all rows to add the requirements that belong to the current group
            For j = 2 To lastRow
                ' If the "Heading Group" (Column B) matches the current group
                If ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = currentGroup Then
                    ' Append the requirement to the reqText string
                    reqText = reqText & vbCrLf & ws.Cells(j, 1).Value ' Add requirement text
                End If
            Next j
            
            ' Write the accumulated requirements for the group to the Word document
            WordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = reqText
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Save and display the document
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 "GeneratedRequirements.docx"
    WordApp.Visible = True
End Sub


Are Heading group and Select group always same?

Add WordApp.Visible = True and step through the loop to see what it's doing.


Collect desired Select Group (Inlcude = JA) with Dict object
Extract data from the first col for each group

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sTxt As String, vKey
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, arrData
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' collect the desired groups
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 4) = "JA" Then
            sTxt = arrData(i, 3) ' Select Group
            If Not objDic.exists(sTxt) Then
                objDic(sTxt) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' extract Requirement
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sTxt = arrData(i, 2) ' Heading Group
        If objDic.exists(sTxt) Then
            objDic(sTxt) = objDic(sTxt) & vbCr & arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    sTxt = ""
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        sTxt = sTxt & vbCr & "Group: " & vKey & objDic(vKey)
    Next
    ' Debug.Print sTxt
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
    ' Create Word Application and Document
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    ' write to Doc
    WordDoc.Range.Text = Mid(sTxt, 2)
    ' Save and display the document
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\GeneratedRequirements.docx"
    WordApp.Visible = True
    ' WordApp.Quit
End Sub


Microsoft documentation:

Range.Text property (Word)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


